# Can not use useState to change array data on function component

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

I have a list when users click each item will change my array data.

my gender array first data is this:

```
[
  {optionName: "Man", sex: 1, selected: true},
  {optionName: "Woman", sex: 1, selected: false}
]
```

```
const [genderOption, setGenderOption] = useState(gender);

      onItemPress = (item, i) => {
        console.log('print i', i);
        console.log('click genderOption', genderOption);

        genderOption.map((value, index) => {
          genderOption[index].selected = false;
        } );

        console.log('after genderOption', genderOption);

        genderOption[i].selected = true;

        console.log('final genderOption', genderOption);
        // setGenderOption([...genderOption]);

        // setTimeout(() => {
        //   console.log('timeOut !');
        //   setGenderOption([...genderOption]);
        // }, 5000);
      }

      console.log('genderOption', genderOption);

      return (
        // my listView has onPress function trigger onItemPress()
      );
```

when click index === 0

[image]

when click index === 1

[image]

It is when I use `setTimeout`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily fix this by mapping over the previous state and setting `selected` by comparing the indexes

```js
const onItemPress = (item, i) => {
  setGenderOption(prevState => prevState.map((gender, index) => ({
    ...gender,
    selected: i === index,
  }));
};
```

Comment: It works ! Thanks for your help truly. But why there is a issue in my way ? I think I set a different array to my state. Can you tell me why ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you try to update the original data items directly within `newGender.map` iteration.

```
newGender.map((value, index) => {
  console.log('before', genderOption[index].selected);
  genderOption[index].selected = false; <------ this line is wrong
  console.log('after', genderOption[index].selected);
} );
```

change it like below, it should be correct

```
const newGender = genderOption.map((value, index) => ({
  ...value,
  selected = false,
}));
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I must be tired. I correct my code to `newGender`, the selected result both of them still `true`.

Comment: I comment `setGenderOption([...newGender]);` the result will be `[
  {optionName: "Man", sex: 1, selected: false},
  {optionName: "Woman", sex: 1, selected: true}
]
`

Comment: So weird, Can you check how time `onItemPress` being called when pressing one of the items? use `console.log` and print what is the value of the index `i` in each call.

Comment: Yes, I check it call just once. I update my question to let it more clear to see my issue, can you check it agin plz. Thanks you very much.

Comment: If I set a dummy array to `setGenderOption([ {optionName: "Man", sex: 1, selected: false}, {optionName: "Woman", sex: 1, selected: true} ]);`, it works.

Comment: then maybe it's because you update the original data directly, I have Updated my answer, you can check if it works or not.

Comment: Yes, It should be worked.  Just like @Asaf Aviv answer. But Why I can't just change the original data directly ?

Comment: As far as I know, in react (and react-native) compare objects using shallow compare (===) for re-rendering purpose, so when you try to change an item in an array directly, actually the array reference itself will not change, in other word objects must be updated through `setState` method to making sure their references will be changed. I'm not familiar with hook mechanism in new versions of React but probably it has the same mechanism that causes the strength behavior you saw in your code. I'll update my post if I found any other precise information about that.

Comment: Thanks Saeed Zhiany, the information helps me a lot. I get it now. Thank you.